# Can't set a global variable within geocoding function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

i got this function:

```
function myfunc()
{
    var x;
    geo.geocode({ 'latLng': marker.getPosition() }, function (results, status) {
    somestuff...
    x = what i need;
    });
    alert(x); //x undefined...
}
```

The geocoding function is working properly...
How can I solve this problem??

Comment: `window.x = what you need` Remember to keep update the local copy as well, because the geocode function might break otherwise.

Comment: it happens on 'dragend' marker event

Comment: When ever the anonymous function passed to `geo.geocode` is executed then the value of x will be set. Since `x` is undefined in the alert the function isn't called yet, It's most likely a callback i.e. it will be called in response to some event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you set `x` inside a `callback function`. You set the callback and after that you call `alert()`, but the `callback function` might not have been executed at that point.